# Adding a response/comment to PDF note – ghostscript

Tags: java, ghostscript

Is there a way, to add a response / comment to an existing PDF note using ghostscript? I can't find helpful information on my research.

Why?
I have german text and what to translate it into english using DeepL API. The translated text should add to the original PDF note as response/comment.

In a test document I will find the marker from that response/comment. But I can't find any examples of how to deal with it in ghostscript. I am interested in adding a response/comment automatically.

I think it is not a good idea to add a new note at a similar place. The overview would suffer.

Comment: There are many libraries for editing, commenting or filling pdf forms beyond ghostscript. Is there a programming language you are familiar with?

Comment: I'm in a java environment wit groovy as scripting language.

Comment: In Java there is an excellent [iText](https://itextpdf.com/resources/downloads) library for PDF manipulation by Bruno Lowagie that you can use either for free under AGPLv3 or commercially.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Adding objects into a pre-existing PDF is not the purpose of GhostScript.</strike>  
As pointed out by KenS, GhostScript may well have the power to add extra related comments. However as we shall see the copious amounts of data per entry would challenge OS shell command line usage and require considerable supporting data per object, so be totally impractical as a working method.

You would need to write a customised editing script in PostScript Compatible "PDFMark" syntax and that is not easy from scratch, since you need to find the existing annotation /NM identities. Adding replied /IRT comments to existing comments is part of Collaborative PDF Workflow and thus mainly the prerogative of Adobe FDF toolkit.

One of the issues with secondary replies to comments are they are not cluttering the page thus are unseen until opening their parent comment. However they can be exported and imported easily for collaborative working.

[image]

If we have the initial File with just a parent comment, we can EITHER open that file and import secondary replies,
[image]

OR simpler OPEN the secondary comments data file and it will import the parent PDF

[image]

The biggest issue then is how to compose the comments data file so here is that simple example. Where you can see the first comment has Name `NM(810b4c82-e36d-4ecf-86f5-a53ba1b4656b)` and the reply has IRT (in response to) `/IRT(810b4c82-e36d-4ecf-86f5-a53ba1b4656b)`

```
%FDF-1.2
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</FDF<</Annots[2 0 R 3 0 R 4 0 R]/F(/C/Users/lez/Downloads/simple1 \(mu1a\).pdf)/ID[<><>]/UF(/C/Users/lez/Downloads/simple1 \(mu1a\).pdf)>>/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</BS<</Type/Border/W 0>>/C[1 1 0]/Contents(This is a text box comment)/DA(/Helv 12 Tf 0 0 0 rg)/DS(font: Helvetica,sans-serif 12.0pt; text-align:left; color:#000000 )/F 4/M(D:20231011212158+01'00')/NM(810b4c82-e36d-4ecf-86f5-a53ba1b4656b)/Page 0/RC(<?xml version="1.0"?><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:APIVersion="Acrobat:23.6.0" xfa:spec="2.0.2"  style="font-size:12.0pt;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-weight:normal;font-style:norma\
l;font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;font-stretch:normal"><p>This is a text box comment</p></body>)/Rect[360.784 695.791 522.724 714.52]/Subtype/FreeText/T( )/Type/Annot>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</C[1.0 0.0 0.0]/Contents(Dies ist eine Antwort auf einen Textfeldkommentar und kann daher in einer anderen Sprache verfasst sein)/CreationDate(D:20231011211528+01'00')/F 28/IRT(810b4c82-e36d-4ecf-86f5-a53ba1b4656b)/M(D:20231011211943+01'00')/NM(a34807a7-9440-4631-8ef8-73421cb57e10)/Name/Comment/Page 0/Popup 4 0 R/RC(<?xml version="1.0"?><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:APIVersion="Acrobat:23.6.0" xfa:spec="2.0.2" ><p dir="ltr"><span dir="ltr" style="font-size:9.9pt;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-we\
ight:normal;font-style:normal">Dies ist eine Antwort auf einen Textfeldkommentar und kann daher in einer anderen Sprache verfasst sein</span></p></body>)/Rect[360.784 690.52 384.784 714.52]/Subj(Note1)/Subtype/Text/Type/Annot>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</F 28/Open true/Page 0/Parent 3 0 R/Rect[612.0 622.52 796.0 714.52]/Subtype/Popup/Type/Annot>>
endobj
trailer
<</Root 1 0 R>>
%%EOF
```

Thus most programmable PDF readers will be able to import 1000's of replies and resave the file ONCE even via command line. However to do that with Ghostscript with so much text would require 1000 separate programming lines of one per comment and the file would bloat many fold.

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I agree that adding objects to a PDF file is not the purpose of Ghostscript. Many things people do with Ghostscript are not its original purpose. I don't know what you mean by "write a customised editing script in Postscript format" You can't 'edit' a PDF file with Ghostscript at all. However, if all you want to do is add a new annotation then you can do that by using a pdfmark with a single line of PostScript. I doubt that it's significantly  easier with any other library. It does assume you already know the original Annot, you can't have GS find that for you.